# revalidateTag does not change cache

Tags: caching, next.js13

I have version 13.4.13. I am trying to use revalidateTag to update cache. well when i refresh the `http://localhost:3000/a` url Nothing happens. Why cache doesn't change ?

**/app/a**

```
async function A() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/a?tag=collection', {
    method: 'POST',
    next: { tags: ['collection'] },
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  return (
    <>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default A;
```

**/api/a/route**

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const tag = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('tag') as string;
  revalidateTag(tag);
  return NextResponse.json(`${Math.random()}`);
}
```